# Resolve a PHPCS error in a Laravel migration file

Tags: laravel, migration, psr-2, psr-1

In all my laravel migrations I want to use PSR2, but I getting a warning.

```
 use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

    use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;

    class CreatePlayersTable extends Migration {
      // migration 
    }
```

The error phpcs warning is **Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level (a top-level vendor name)**

How can I fix this warning?

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53919231/resolve-this-error-for-laravel-migration-file-each-class-must-be-in-a-namespace, which has one answer.