# Resolve this error for Laravel migration file: Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level

Tags: laravel, phpcs

How to resolve this phpcs error? It shows up for the class `Keyword` in all Laravel migrations files. The error message is:

> Each class must be in a namespace of at least one level (a top-level
>   vendor name) phpcs

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do it several different ways:

First, you can put this at the top of your file:

```
// phpcs:disable PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace
```

Second, you can use:

```
// @codingStandardsIgnoreLine
```

Just before your class declaration.

Hope any one of these will work for you.
If the problem still persists please let me know about this.

Comment: Added to `phpcs.xml` as below and worked
`<rule ref="PSR1"><exclude name="PSR1.Classes.ClassDeclaration.MissingNamespace" /></rule>`